# Render Php file then return it as html

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to render a php file and then return it as html to send in an email, how would I go about doing this? Here is an example of the code that I'm using:

```
public function setPHP($php)
{
    ob_start();
    $phpsend = ( include $php );
    $this->html = (string) ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the function.

```
    $php = file_get_contents( NHM_PLUGIN_DIR . 'assets/templates/newhomesguide.php' );
    $css = file_get_contents( NHM_PLUGIN_DIR . 'assets/css/email_template.css' );

    $cssToInlineStyles->setPHP($php);
    $cssToInlineStyles->setCSS($css);
```

I'm trying to modify CSSToInlineStyles by Tijs Verkoyen, which inlines css with html, I'm just trying do do the same but with a php file that has functionality.

[image]

Comment: Has this approach worked for you? Have you even tried it? What part isn't working?

Comment: You have to be a little bit more specific on what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the post with the error

Comment: what abt `include()` ?

Comment: I don't undertand. To inline a php with another php you just have to  use `include`

Comment: When I use include in place of include_once I get the same error. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Actually, you pass some source code to "include()". I think "include()" does expect a file name as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close. This is how I would do it. The evaluated file will be in `$this->html` like you want and it will immediately be sent to the output stream after being evaluated.

```
public function setPHP($php)
{
    if(!file_exists($php)) // Some error handling here maybe?
      die('File ' . $php . ' DNE');

    // Eval the $php file and store it in a variable
    ob_start();
    include $php;
    $this->html = ob_get_clean();

    // Send the evaluated file to the output stream
    echo $this->html;
}
```

Comment: How is it useless? I've done this a million times. You might want to try it and read the manual to see that it works.

Comment: @DanielBeauyat The [documentation](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) illustrates this exact same example. RTFM!

Comment: @DanielBeauyat You clearly have no idea how `ob_start` works. You can use it at any place in the code. It starts another point in the output buffer stack. Again [RTFM!!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: Just read. @quickshiftin: You're right! Well, I'll delete my first comments. Thank you very much!